# How to use local varaiable containing a string to reference the name of a Global Variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, prometheus

I have a script in which I'm trying to iterate through a list of strings, then take the value of the current variable, convert it to upper-case, then use use the result as a variable name. The end result will be to set the value of a prometheus metric, which is a global variable.

```
from prometheus_client import start_http_server, Gauge


# List of strings (global variables will be equal but upper-case)
MEASUREMENTS = ['x', 'y', 'z']

# Prometheus Metrics set as global variables
X = Gauge('some_value', 'some_description', ['label1', 'label2']
Y = Gauge('some_value', 'some_description', ['label1', 'label2']
Z = Gauge('some_value', 'some_description', ['label1', 'label2']

...

    # Iterate through list of strings
    for measurement in MEASUREMENTS:                                    
        metric = getattr(some_status, measurement)  # Will be an integer                                    
        upper_measurement = measurement.upper()     # Will equal the global variable name                                 
        [?UPPER_MEASUREMENT?].labels(label1=value_P1, label_2=value).set(metric)  # This is where I need to reference the global variable name
```

Effectively this:

```
[?UPPER_MEASUREMENT?].labels(label1=value_P1, label_2=value).set(metric)
```

Needs to be:

```
X.labels(label1=value_P1, label_2=value).set(metric)
```

I tried:

```
upper_measurement.labels(label1=value_P1, label_2=value).set(metric)
```

But of course that will result in an error since it's a string:

```
Error: 'str' object has no attribute 'labels'
```

Not quite sure where to go from here. I could just write a big ugly block setting each metric, but I'd rather avoid that if possible.

Comment: You could define a dictionary globally, and use x,y,z as keys values.

Comment: I tried that initially, but that is still going to end up with a string being passed and get the same result.

Comment: To be clear, I meant `{'x':Gauge('some_value', 'some_description', ['label1', 'label2']
'y':Gauge('some_value', 'some_description', ['label1', 'label2']
'z': Gauge('some_value', 'some_description', ['label1', 'label2']}`

Comment: You should definitely be using a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your metrics in a dictionary:

```
METRICS = {
    key: Gauge('some_value', 'some_description', ['label1', 'label2']) 
    for key in ['x', 'y', 'z']
}
```

and then you can easily update all the metrics by iterating over the dictionary:

```
for key, metric in METRICS.items():                                    
    metric.labels(label1=value_P1, label_2=value).set(getattr(some_status, key))
```

Comment: Omg, thank you. I was working through the comments above and didn't quite get how it all went together. Makes sense now. Thanks!

Comment: One more thing I should have made clear in the original post: 'some_value' and 'some_description' need to be unique for each Gauge.  That is "x" should be "key: Gauge('x', 'Some metric about x'. . .)" and "y" should be "key: Gague('y', some metric about 'y'" . . .) Is there a tidy way to accomplish this?

Comment: `key: Gauge(key, f"Some metric about {key}" ...)`  There's no rule saying you can only use a variable once.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Even though I think the correct way of doing this should be using a Dictionary as other answers have pointed out, but if you still want to know, you could do this with `eval()`. So, with just changing

```
[?UPPER_MEASUREMENT?].labels(label1=value_P1, label_2=value).set(metric)
```

with

```
eval(upper_measurement).labels(label1=value_P1, label_2=value).set(metric)
```

it should work. Beware if you're getting the elements of the `MEASUREMENTS` list from some input that you can't sanitize before using `eval()`, because it can potentially run dangerous code.